# Large banks collapsing verses a single countries economic decline

Tags: banking, financial-crises

Please excuse anything i get wrong here i am in no way a economics expert but i am interested in the subject.

Earlier today I saw someone make a post about how banks like CitiGroup have been given $trillions in bailouts, and that Greece is in need of a much smaller bailout yet they are finding it difficult to get that. just want to reiterate that is not my opinion as i dont have enough information to form one yet but its just something i read. I'm guessing the post is massively misinformed and its probably not that simple since it was on Facebook.

I would assume that the reason banks like CitiGroup get larger bailouts is because their decline is more detrimental to global economy than Greece's decline would be? (just a guess)

So to my question, Can anyone explain (or point me to a resource than can explain) to me why banks tend to get larger bailouts (if that's even true) and what effects a large bank failing has on world economy verses a country similar to Greece's economy collapsing and what effects that would have on the rest of the world.

Again apologies for any incorrect terminology, as i said at the top im not an expert or even a student in the field of economics i'm just trying to get a better understanding on how banks affect the global economy verses how a country affects the global economy

for reference here is a copy and past of the post i saw;

> The current estimate is that Greece needs a bailout of around
>   370billion. No one wants to know. meanwhile have a look at these
>   bailouts and the banks that had no problem getting them from tax
>   payers like you and me.
>
> citigroup - $2.513 trillion,
>
> Morgan Stanley - $2.041 trillion,
>
> Merrill Lynch - $1.949 trillion,
>
> Bank of America - $1.344 trillion,
>
> Barclays PLC - $868 billion,
>
> Goldman Sachs - $814 billion,
>
> Royal Bank Of Scotland - $541 billion,
>
> JP Morgan CHase - $391 billion,
>
> Deutsche Bank - $354 Billion

Comment: I voted to close, as this question is not answerable in this form. (A) I don't think the number very far from correct (B) the money giving organizations are completely different (C) the problem in with Greece is not about the amount of money but about the measures taken by the Greek government (D) even if the numbers were correct, you would be comparing guarantees with "gifts" ... So, the question is comparing things that are not even similar.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBob fair enough i kind of guessed that comparing banks to countries was a bit dumb. i was kind of looking for an experts opinion on the statement and for the reasons behind their opinions preferably backed up with evidence, i guess i messed up the asking though, i will see if i can close it, thanks